# Combining BottomTabNavigator and StackNavigator [React Navigation v5 / Android]

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have a tab bar, and I want to make it so that when one of the tabs is pressed, it will push a screen onto the stack (covering the tab bar). It's basically a combination of a StackNavigator and BottomTabNavigator. I tried this but it gives me an error saying "navigation" is undefined.

> App.js

```
const AppContainer = createStackNavigator(
  {
    SnapTalk: Tabs,
    Post: {
      screen: PostScreen
    }
  },
  {
    mode: "modal",
    headerMode: "none",
    initialRouteName: "Post"
  }const AppContainer = createStackNavigator(
  {
    SnapTalk: Tabs,
    Post: {
      screen: PostScreen
    }
  },
  {
    mode: "modal",
    headerMode: "none",
    initialRouteName: "Post"
  }
```

> NavBar.js

```
         <AppTabs.Screen 
            name="Post"
            component = {PostScreen} 
            options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size}) => (
                    <Icon name="ios-add-circle-outline" size={30} color= {color} />
                )
            }} 
             listeners={{
               tabPress: 
                 navigation.navigate("Post")
            }}
        >
```

Comment: I'm assuming becuase of the error mentioned, it's coming from NavBar.js? Where in that file is navigation defined? Should you be deconstructing it from the.props or props?

Comment: @JacobBralish I am not sure where I'm supposed to define navigation... Sorry, I'm new to React/React-Native. Do you need more info?

Comment: I do, I dont know if the error is coming from app.js or navbar.js. is your navbar.js a stateless functional component or a full class component?